# A faster solution to this equation: $e^{-ix}(1+e^{-ix}) = -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, alternative-proof

I want to find $x$ such that

$$e^{-ix}(1+e^{-ix}) = -1$$

I was able to see that it was the same as $\cos x = -0.5$ with a bit of work, but I think there must be a faster way since usually questions from GATE exam have elegant solutions.

Let me give some context, I needed to solve this equation in order to find the frequencies rejected by a digital system. Question 10.2 (GATE IN 2003 digital systems rejection of frequencies cause gain is zero)

[image: question 10.2 from GATE IN 2003]

The following is my attempt

[image: my attempt to find x]

So I wanted an alternative way to solve it, it would be nice if it was faster by hand and also any fast way to find the general form for x once we it's a set of angles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just a quadratic equation in $z=e^{-ix}$, where $\cos(x)=\operatorname{Re}(z)$. Use the quadratic formula to solve
$$z^2+z+1=0,$$
to find that $z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i$, and hence that $\cos(x)=\operatorname{Re}(z)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I can use this idea to solve a whole class of problems.

Comment: There is a typo: ‘$x=\text{Re}(z)$’.

Comment: @Szeto Fixed, thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
e^{-ix}\left(1+e^{-ix}\right)=-1 &\quad\to\quad1 + e^{-ix} = -e^{ix} \\[6pt]
&\quad\to\quad e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=-1 \\[6pt]
&\quad\to\quad \frac12\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right) = -\frac12 \\[6pt]
&\quad\to\quad \cos x = -\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: Really neat! I knew cos x could be written in this form, but I never saw that the equation could be manipulated like this!

Answer (score 3):

Just take modulus and square the equation. You will get $\cos\, x=-0.5$ immediately.

$$|e^{-ix}|^{2} |1+e^{-ix}|^{2}= |-1|^{2}$$

$$1 \times \left ( (1+\cos x)^2 +(-\sin x)^2 \right ) = 1$$

$$ 2 + 2 \cos x = 1 $$

So $\cos\, x=\frac{1-2}{2}$!!

Comment: Taking the modulus might give false solutions. For example, $e^{ix}=1$ has only one point on the unit circle as a solution, but $|e^{ix}|=1$ is satisfied by every real $x$.

Comment: What I am saying is that taking modulus tells you that $\cos \, x$ must be $-0.5$ if it all there is a solution $x$. This proves rigorously that there is no solution with $\cos \, x \neq -0.5$ and then yo u have to go back to the equation and verify that this indeed gives a solution.